# Running certain operation after every 2 hours in shell script

Tags: android, shell

Is there any ideal implementation to do a certain operation every 2 hours in shell scripting?
Since I aim this operation for an android phone I worry about the battery life and cpu consumption the shell script can cause if I create an infinite loop with `busybox sleep 2hours` and my operation within the loop. Can anyone me show a better implementation which can use minimum cpu time?

Comment: Sleep doesn't create much (almost no) CPU time so you don't have to worry about it the whole time it runs. Also, bash just waits for it (sleep) so bash doesn't really use much CPU power.

Comment: Ohk thanks, can you tell me the number for 2 hours? Is the parameter for sleep to be in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: Depends on the version of sleep. busybox sleep 2h should work.

Comment: Thanks 2h seems valid. You can combine both your answers and post the proper answer. It will help anyone else. I will mark it as accept.

Comment: Done. I added some other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep doesn't create much (almost no) CPU time so you don't have to worry about it the whole time it runs. Also, bash just waits for it (sleep) so bash doesn't really use much CPU power.

To run sleep for 2 hours use the 2h argument. With busybox it's buxybox sleep 2h. If we are going to place it inside a loop we could do it this way:

```
while busybox sleep 2h; do
    ... do some tasks or run checks
done
```

Or

```
while
    ... do some tasks or run checks
    busybox sleep 2h
do
    continue
done
```

That would prevent another task from executing if sleep is suddenly interrupted like when shutting down or when keyboard interrupt signal is sent.

You might consider checking this post I made before as well: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/optimizing-bash-process-4175431381/#post4802416

It accepts input instead of doing sleeps but minor modifications could prove it helpful too.

Comment: Ah! wide variety of ways I didn't knew. Thanks a lot!